# Add break line inside React JSX textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, textarea, break

I am trying to add break line inside array map that is printed inside textarea and it's working fine, but as soon as I get the mail the break line is not showing anymore, all of my text is in one line.

```
 const product = cartItems.map((item) => item.name + item.sub).join("\r\n");

 <textarea
   type="text"
   id="product"
   name="product"
   value={product}
   readOnly
   required
 />
```

my output inside the textarea is correct, like this:

```
Name Sub
Name Sub
Name Sub
```

but when i send out the mail the print is:

```
Name Sub  Name Sub  Name Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
const product = cartItems.map((item) => item.name + item.sub).join("\r\n");
<>
<textarea
type="text"
id="product"
name="product"
value={product}
readOnly
required
/>
<br/>
</>
```

just put a physical linebreak?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the linebreak is not working and it's outside the textarea content, the value should have the line break.